# filezilla local side unable to see ext4 drive created with mdadm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filezilla, mdadm

I have an ubuntu machine that has an external HD enclosure with 4 single terabyte drives. I used mdadm to group all four drives into a raid 6 array. This drive functions perfectly, and I use it to store all kinds of stuff. I've shared it across my home network and can copy to/from the drive no problem. But filezilla cannot.

This is on the local side, when I am choosing a download location to store the files at. For some reason filezilla cannot see the drive. I have started filezilla from the command line, with the --local option set to a folder within the raid 6 drive, and it will open fine, but will not show any files within that folder. And when I try to download something to that folder with filezilla opened in this fashion, I get error messages that say (very unhelpfully) that errors occurred attempting to write to disk.

I also created a symbolic link ("ln -s") in my home folder to the drive, but filezilla doesn't care which way I get to the drive. It either cannot see the drive, or if I start it with the local path pointing to the drive, it cannot write to the drive.

To be clear, we are not talking about where I am FTP'ing from. My internet searches indicate a problem when the FTP server has files located on an ext4 drive. But this is when I am trying to download files TO the ext4 drive. Not the other way around.

No other programs exhibit the same difficulty as filezilla.

Any advice?